# Registry values not getting stored in database

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am reading `Registry key` values and storing them in `string variables`, and passing these values as parameters in `NewReg` method to store them into database, but i am getting this error message `you must use an updateable query` and therefore this message `user not added in database`,

where I am going wrong? How I can achieve this ?

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    DBHandling db = new DBHandling();

    public LoginForm()
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\StudentExm");

            string usrname = registryKey.GetValue("UserName").ToString();
            string password = registryKey.GetValue("Password").ToString();
            string emailId = registryKey.GetValue("EmailID").ToString();
            string contctno = registryKey.GetValue("ContactNo").ToString();
            string regDate = registryKey.GetValue("RegDate").ToString();
            registryKey.Close();

            if (NewReg(usrname, password, emailId, contctno, regDate))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User Name: " + usrname + "\n" +
                    "Password: " + password + "\n" +
                    "Email ID: " + emailId + "\n" +
                    "Contact No: " + contctno + "\n" +
                    "Reg Date: " + regDate);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User not added in the database.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**NewReg method in DBHandling Class**

```
public bool NewReg(string usrName, string passwrd, string emailID, string contactNo,string regdat)
{
    bool flag = false;

    try
    {
        //string sql = "INSERT INTO test(nametest,pass,email,contact,regdate) Values('" + usrName + "','" + passwrd + "','" + emailID + "','" + contactNo + "','" + System.DateTime.Now + "')";
        string sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo([UserName],[Password],[email],[contact],[regdate]) Values(@UserInfo,@Password,@email,@contact,@regdate)";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] {
            new OleDbParameter("@UserName", usrName),
            new OleDbParameter("@Password", passwrd),
            new OleDbParameter("@EmailID", emailID),
            new OleDbParameter("@ContactNo", contactNo),
            new OleDbParameter("@RegDate", regdat)
        });

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        flag = true;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you add code for the NewReg method so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @DustinDavis  I have added NewReg method code

Comment: Is this going to an access database or SQL CE or some file based store?

Comment: It's a file permissions issue. Make sure the account the app is running under has proper permissions. To start off I would give 'Everyone' full access to make sure that fixes it. Then narrow down the security issues from there.

Comment: Check the permission of the registry folder.  Make sure it has read/write access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess the Problem Because of this Line:

```
string usrname = registryKey.GetValue("UserName") + Environment.NewLine;
```

The Code U can change like this and Try.

```
 string usrname = registryKey.GetValue("UserName").ToString();
```

Were as you are assigning the Value with `+ Environment.NewLine;`. It should not be.,

That is why `you must use an updateable query` error message.

And this is Your Custom Message `user not added in database`. Because of Condition Fails its getting displayed.

*Hope it helps., :)*

Comment: `NewReg()`  Function is ok.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, it's a file permissions issue.

This error USUALLY occurs when you attempts to perform an UPDATE or
some other action that alters the information in the database.

> This error occurs because dataobjects what ever ado or ADO.NET  is
>   unable to write to the Microsoft Access database **due to insufficient
>   write/modify permissions**, which can be easily fixed by granting
>   read/write to IUSR_ and IWAM_.
>
> **`IUSR_<machineName>`** and **`IWAM_<machineName>`** come into focus when an anonymous web user needs to modify the Microsoft Access
>   database & while doing so Jet creates an .ldb file to handle database
>   locking. If the above mentioned 2 users don't have the necessary
>   permissions, the lock file isn't created & ultimately the Microsoft
>   Access database can't be modified..

**FIX:**

> To fix this problem, right click on the folder which holds the
>   Microsoft Access database & choose properties. Use the Security tab in
>   Explorer to adjust the properties for this folder so that the Internet
>   Guest account has the correct writable permissions.
>
> Also make sure that the MDB file itself isn't marked as read-only, and
>   that you don't have the MDB file open; particularly in exclusive mode;
>   while trying to reach the Microsoft Access database from ASP

**source:** http://forums.asp.net/t/154273.aspx/9/10

Comment: I don't see this option ` everyone group ` in Security tab of Access file Property window

Comment: You have to add it in. In security tab, click edit on the groups list, then click 'Add'. Then type in everyone in the text box and then click 'Ok'.

Comment: I have that database access file in `Debug` folder, so should I change the properties of this Folder or Property of `database Access File`?  because here  http://forums.asp.net/t/154273.aspx/9/10 i see this line  `Right Click on FOlder where mdb file is placed and Select Properties`

Comment: either one. But start by setting it on the folder.

Comment: In Properties of debug Folder I am Uncheking Read-only Checkbox ,But bydefault it is getting checked again  dont know why ,hence my issue persist still der

Comment: Don't store it in the debug folder.

Comment: Where do I store it than?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
[image]

```
 string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\Node[Name]";
        string valueName = "Value"; // Value in registry Ex. RegDate
        object Obj = Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, "Exist");
        if (Obj == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Do your Code .... 
        }
```